# How to check property in array with currently selected file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have condition on file upload so onSelect i have implemented conditions , `fileNames` variable is getting list of files that are currently selected by user but has not save to database. `AssessmentData` is Json response that are saved in database. So How can i set condition if `fileNames` is already existed in `assessmentData` throw an error and prevent user to add same fileName..

main.js

```
rcsaAssessmentService.getAlldocs(id).then(function(response){
          assessmentData = response.data;
        });


     $scope.onSelect = function (e) {
            var fileNames = $.map(e.files, function(file) { return file.name; }).join(', ');
            selectedFile.forEach(function (file) { 
              if (fileNames === file) { 
                e.preventDefault();
                $timeout(function () {
                  $scope.showErr= true;
                  }); 
              }
              else { 
                $scope.showErr = false; 
                } 
              });
            for ( var i=0; i < e.files.length; i++){
              selectedFile.push(e.files[i].name);
            }
          };
```

JSON.JS

assessmentData response

```
[
    {
        "attchDesc": "test ",
        "attchTypLookUpCD": null,
        "riskAssessmentKey": null,
        "uploadedTs": "2015-07-06",
        "fileName": "Risk Assessment_SIT Open Defects_0409.xlsx",
        "uploadedBy": "ZKZ1KCY",
        "riskAssessmentAtachKey": 1115,
        "file": null
    },
    {
        "attchDesc": "test",
        "attchTypLookUpCD": null,
        "riskAssessmentKey": null,
        "uploadedTs": "2015-07-06",
        "fileName": "abc.xlsx",
        "uploadedBy": "ZKZ1KCY",
        "riskAssessmentAtachKey": 1116,
        "file": null
    }
]
```

Comment: what is `selectedFile` and why is it an array?

Comment: i dont need selectedFile any more now i have assessmentData i will be checking with currently selected files with database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what selectedFile is, but this is a solution to see if a value is in an array:

```
rcsaAssessmentService.getAlldocs(id).then(function(response){
  assessmentData = response.data;
});

$scope.onSelect = function (e) {
  var fileNames = assessmentData.map(function(assesment){
    return assessment.fileName;
  });

  e.files.forEach(function (file) {
    if (fileNames.indexOf(file.name) !== -1) { // filename was present
      e.preventDefault();
      $timeout(function () {
        $scope.showErr= true;
      });
    }
    else {
      $scope.showErr = false;
    }
  });
  for ( var i=0; i < e.files.length; i++){
    selectedFile.push(e.files[i].name);
  }
};
```

Comment: selectedFile is array of files once user select the file i am sending it selectedFile object , But above question is i have to check if file name is present in the assessmentData response that are saved files in database, So how to check condition with that scenario..

Comment: change the map function to `var fileNames = assessmentData.map(function(assesment){  return assessment.fileName })`

Comment: i dont understand map can you please edit above code so i can implement..I will appreciate that

Comment: `var result = myArray.map(myFunction)` will execute `myFunction(item)` once per element in `myArray`. `myFunction` should return something. `result` will end up being the 'mapped' values returned by myFunction. editing...